# "nice and good" vs "nice and well"

Tags: grammar

What would be proper grammar? "I cleaned the counters nice and good" or "I cleaned the counters nice and well"? Or is "nice and ___" slang and in itself improper? And even if it is improper, what exactly is it meaning?

Obviously the key is whether "good/well" is describing the cleaning or describing the counters.

"I cleaned the counters (to be) nice and good"
"I cleaned the counters (and they are) nice and good"

"I painted the counters white" has "white" describing the counters and not the act of painting. (or does it describe the painting? I'm not sure)

"I scrubbed the counters clean" is probably a better example.

Comment: As far as I know, "nice and ______" is not an idiom.  "Good and _____" is an idiom.  For example, "I scrubbed the counters ***good and hard***" (FWIW, not my downvote)

Comment: That's all well and good but you know good and well that idioms don't accept substitutions.  Nice as that might be.

Comment: I cleaned the counters [spick and span](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/spick-and-span).

Comment: 'nice and good' is the way to say, but it is informal and wouldn't sound right in a more formal situation. Often people call using an informality in a formal situation as 'bad grammar' but really it is just a different variety (which is rule bound).

Answer (score 0):

"Good" is an adjective. "Well" is an adverb. Since you are modifying the verb "clean", then you should use "well."

Comment: Tello’s “Good" and ”Well" is correct in itself but Jonathan’s original worry about improper “nice and ___" over-rides all, as might be obvious when it is omitted.

“I cleaned the counters nice” can change to “nicely”?

“… good" is simply wrong.

“… well” is fine.

“… nicely and good” remains wrong.

“… nicely and well” could be grammatically correct but are there really instances in which “nicely” and “well” are not interchangeable?